# The Socket.IO mounted on FastAPI app works fine when mounted on the root route ('/'), but encounters issues when changing it to '/ws'

Tags: python, socket.io, python-asyncio, fastapi, python-socketio

The Socket.IO app, which is mounted to the FastAPI app on the root route ('/'), is functioning correctly. However, when I attempt to change the route from the root ('/') to '/ws', the Socket.IO functionality is not working as expected.

here is the server.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from typing import Union

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["Content-Disposition"],
)


@app.middleware("http")
async def cors_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    if request.url.path == "/ws":
        # Exclude the /ws route from CORS headers
        response = await call_next(request)
    else:
        # Apply CORS headers for other routes
        response = await call_next(request)
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "*"
    return response


# @app.get("/ws")
# def read_root():
#     return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Union[str, None] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}


from sockets import sio_app

app.mount('/ws', sio_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", reload=True, port=1111)
```

here is sockets.py

```
import socketio
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status

sio_server = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='asgi',
                                  cors_allowed_origins='*')

sio_app = socketio.ASGIApp(socketio_server=sio_server,
                           # socketio_path="sockets"
                           )

active_connections = []


@sio_server.event
async def connect(sid, environ, auth):
    print(f'connected auth={auth} sid={sid}')
    active_connections.append(sid)
    print(f"Active connections:- {str(active_connections)}")
    await sio_server.emit('chat', {'data': 'Connected', 'sid': sid}, room=sid)


@sio_server.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnected', sid)
    active_connections.remove(sid)
    print(f"Active connections:- {str(active_connections)}")


@sio_server.on('query')
async def test_message(sid, message):
    print(message)
    await sio_server.emit('chat', {'data': message + " -Interaction Engine"}, room=sid)

# server --> query
#
# client --> chat
```

here is client.py

```
import socketio
import asyncio

sio = socketio.AsyncClient()


async def connect():
    try:
        connection_task = asyncio.create_task(sio.connect('http://localhost:1111/ws', auth={"token": "dataa121asdadsassda"}))
        await asyncio.wait_for(connection_task, timeout=30)
        print('Connected to server')
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('Connection timed out')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error occurred while connecting: {str(e)}')


@sio.on('connect')
async def on_connect():
    print('Connected to server')


@sio.on('chat')
def on_chat(data):
    print('Received message:', data)


@sio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('Disconnected from server')


async def main():
    await connect()

    await sio.emit('query', 'Hello, server!, from client')

    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await sio.disconnect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

have also tried in POSTMAN ,

when I try it using client.py  I am getting bellow error

```
Connection timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bharatkundapur/Documents/Workspace/Socketio_Poc/client.py", line 44, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/bharatkundapur/Documents/Workspace/Socketio_Poc/client.py", line 36, in main
    await sio.emit('query', 'Hello, server!, from client')
  File "/Users/bharatkundapur/Documents/Workspace/Envs/Socketio_Poc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/asyncio_client.py", line 213, in emit
    raise exceptions.BadNamespaceError(
socketio.exceptions.BadNamespaceError: / is not a connected namespace.
```

when I try using postman I see bellow logs in the server

**connection failed (403 Forbidden)** Postman and same in the postman.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been resolved, and I forgot to share the solution. Here's the answer to the question above.

In the file sockets.py, the socketio_path is not defined, and its default value is socket.io.

When we want to attach the sio_app to the fast API app route '/ws,' we can achieve this by using the following line of code in the server.py:

app.mount('/ws', sio_app)

assuming the app is hosted in the local environment.

However, when attempting to connect and establish a duplex connection through the web socket endpoint, using **http://localhost:8888/ws** is incorrect. Just because we have mounted the **sio_app** at the **'/ws'** route does not mean the sio_app is available at http://localhost:8888/ws.

**The solution is to access the http://localhost:8888/ endpoint with socketio_path='/ws/socket.io'.**